# Printing picture through a variety of sizes small to large

Tags: printing

I have taken pictures and am sending them into the printers to get them blown up. I am starting with a 4 by 6 photo. And I want to a variety of sizes that are up to two feet on one side. I just cannot figure out all the sizes in between to get there. I don't want the photos to be stretched, but retain original proportions. Is there a formula I can use or anything? Basically what are the 6 or so sizes that get me up to 24 " on one side. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The ratio of 4 x 6 is 1.5.

So if you know what the short side should be, just multiply it by 1.5 (or if you know the long side, divide by 1.5 to ascertain the short side).

```
Short side: 12
Long side: 18

Short side: 24
Long side: 36
```

And so on

Comment: Thanks so much.  I couldn't get a solid multiplier because i know 5 x 7 is another standard photo size. It doesn't follow the multiply by 1.5 rule. Does that mean it's slightly distorted or do they just call it 5 x 7 but really it's 5 x 7.5?

Comment: I think 7x5 is standard and that ratio is 1.4. I think alot of labs offer 6 x 4.5 which is closer. but admittedly as these ratios differ it would mean cropping the image at one particular print size. I used to be very anal retentive about that sort of stuff, wanting what was composed in the viewfinder to be printed, and there are different paper sizes, but then I learnt about all the different negative sizes, 6x4.5, 6x6, 6x7, 6x9 and then 4x5 inch and many many more. Arrrrgghhh

Comment: Oh wow,  so its hard to say what the negative size is to know what the view finder would be actually seeing to know what ratio makes the picture true to size?